# Replace a div class with an other class with its events. JQuery

Tags: jquery, class, events, replace

I want to change a div class by an other class with its events, i have this :

```
<ul  class="pants"> 
<li><a href="#"  ><img src="images/1.png" alt="a"  /></a></li>     
<li><a href="#"  ><img src="images/2.png" alt="b"  /></a></li>   
</ul>
<ul  class="tshirts">
<li><a href="#"  ><img src="images/3.png" alt="a"  /></a></li>     
<li><a href="#"  ><img src="images/4.png" alt="b"  /></a></li>   
</ul>
```

JQuery :

```
$('.tshirts a').click(function(){
Alert('This is a pant');
});
```

i've used this to change the class:

```
$('.pants').attr('class','tshirts');
```

the class name changed , but when i click on the list, it dont show the alert . so the event is not raised using this . Can someone Help . thank you all.

Comment: T-Shirts can't be pants!!!

Comment: if you've copy/pasted this code from your solution, mind the quotes `'` and `‘` are not the same. The latter will trigger an error.

Comment: Amit Joki ,Thats just an example ...

Comment: Even with 'tshirts' , still does not work ..

Comment: Changing the class after the event handler is bound doesn't suddenly make the event handler work for those elements. The selector is evaluated at runtime, it doesn't check for the class on each click.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a event to be delegated to static parent or document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tshirts a', function(){
    // alert code
});
```

As the an attribute in the dom has been changed after dom ready and event bound on doc ready will not be available for this element, so instead you have to delegate it to the closest static parent or to the document itself.

and instead of changing attribute you can add/remove the class names with this:

```
$('.pants').toggleClass('pants tshirts');
```

Comment: This is fine, Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the click event, this will bind to the element on page load.

When you update the class name, you will need to bind the click event on these elements also:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tshirts a', function(e) {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: This is fine, Thank you .